# What is the formula for converting x to y here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, change-of-variable

I am trying to figure out how to change from multiplication to division gradually as $x$ increases:

> Given:
>   $$250 \le x \le 1000$$
>   $$480 \ge y \ge 120$$

What is the formula for converting $x$ to $y$?

Is there an easy way to do it with modular arithmetic?

Comment: What do you mean converting to $x$ to $y$?

Comment: oh lmao it's just y = mx + c

Comment: Does $y$ increase with $x$? Otherwise, there're two possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a linear conversion, you want the [two-point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) for the line.  You have two points $(250,480)$ and $(1000,120)$, so $y-480=\frac{1000-250}{120-480}(x-250)$

Comment: yeah I just realised it's just y=mx+c hahahaha

Comment: I assumed $y=480$ went with $x=250$ because of the order you gave them.  This means $y$ goes down when $x$ goes up.  If they should be reversed, you should be able to adjust the formula.  That is why I left it in the form I did, so you can see where the constants come from.